# How to access puppet documentation offline?

Tags: documentation, puppet

Is there any way I can have Puppet complete documenation available offline ? Its hard checking module documentation everytime via browser.

I hope it will help other Puppet module developers.

Thank you.

Comment: If you mean module, then you could just check the `README.md` stored locally. If you mean the resources, then you can use `puppet doc`.

Answer (score 0):

While searching I have found Zeal Application which is like Offline Documentation broweser and that seems supports so many langugages. can be download from Official website here: https://zealdocs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could request to download it from Puppet direct.
https://docs.puppet.com/download/
It will come down as puppetdocs-latest.tar.gz and is currently about 879MB.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the documentation is supposed to be viewable offline if you simply clone it. Go to this link [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet-docs/tree/master/source). However, at this moment, it looks to me like the offline viewing functionality is broken - the relative hyperlinks don't actually work. If you figured out what's wrong, you could probably send in a PR to fix it.